# How to move the XML output from Postgres Function to the left side?

Tags: xml, database, postgresql

```
<AffinityDomains>
  <affinitytoken AFFINITYTOKEN="AP10000418"/>
  <affinitytoken AFFINITYTOKEN="AP10000021"/>
  </AffinityDomains>
```

Guys how can I move the last line in the xml output  aligned to the first line. I'm using CHR Functions and XML Element keywords to generate this XML and populate the output in Postgres table field XML_VALUE

```
BEGIN
l_crlf     := CHR(13)||CHR(10);

FOR i IN c1 LOOP

select xmlelement(name AffinityToken,xmlattributes(
i.Affinity_Token as "AFFINITYTOKEN",
i.email_domain as "EMAILDOMAIN")) into v_gac;           

mainXML := concat(mainxml, v_gac, l_crlf, CHR(9));  

END LOOP;

mainXML := concat(mainxml, '</AffinityDomains>', l_crlf);   
End;
```

Appreciate your time and please let me know for any further information,

Comment: Please show us the query you already used.

Comment: Its the code in the Function as follows,

BEGIN
l_crlf     := CHR(13)||CHR(10);

FOR i IN c1 LOOP
        
select xmlelement(name AffinityToken,xmlattributes(
i.Affinity_Token as "AFFINITYTOKEN",
i.email_domain as "EMAILDOMAIN")) into v_gac;   

mainXML := concat(mainxml, v_gac, l_crlf, CHR(9)); 
       
END LOOP;
  
mainXML := concat(mainxml, '</AffinityDomains>', l_crlf); 
End;

Comment: @user10531062 You're always appending a newline and tab to the end of each "affinitytoken" element, so of course when you append the final closing tag, it will be after one newline and tab, which is what you're getting. The best thing to do is restructure it completely - use STRING_AGG to create the "affinitytoken" elements, so that there is no leading or following delimiter, plus it's much more efficient than a loop, which as far as I can see there's no reason for. Can't show you a code example as there's not enough code in your example to translate correctly, I'd need to see the full code.

Comment: But I have a cursor which loops the value, so using the loop

Comment: It can be done quicker without the cursor. If you really want to keep it like this, do something like `mainXML := RTRIM(mainXML, CHR(9))` before appending the final tag.